# Show $d(c+a, c+b)=d(a,b)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Let $C$ be a code. Show that $d(c+a, c+b)= d(a,b)$ is true, for all $a,b,c \in C$

I am having the problem to understand how this addition is defined, since there are no information about $C$, only that it is a code. Is the code meant to be a finite field?

Comment: You're going to need to give us a bit more detail.  What kind of code?  What metric (Hamming distance?)

Comment: The code is more often than not a subset of an algebraic structure where addition is defined. Such as a vector space (or, more generally a free module) over the alphabet field (or a ring). The code may even be closed under addition itself (e.g. a linear code), but that is not necessary for the validity of this claim. Is $d$ the Hamming distance? Please don't hide such details from us!

Comment: @NickPeterson this is exactly how I got the question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes this is the Hamming distance, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $d$ here, denotes the (Hamming) distance between two code-words of your code and $a,b\in\mathbb{Z_p^n}$.

If so, the statement essentially tells us that if we take two-code words $a,b$ and add another code-word, say $c$, to each one, then the distance between the original pair and the one we take is the same.

An easy way to see why this holds true is by using the-I guess familiar to you-notion of weight, that is, the distance of a code-word from the "zero-word" of your code.

So the weight of a word $a$ is $w(a):=d(a,0)$

That is, the weight of a word represents how many non-zero characters appear in it.

It follows that $d(a,b)=w(a-b)$.

Now we have $d(a+c,b+c)=w(a+c-(b+c))=w(a-b)=d(a,b)$

Comment: @MathemamaticianByMistake thanks!

Comment: @Kiki My pleasure!